# How to execute stored procedure multiple times to insert values in the table

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have following stored procedure that i want to execute in sql server 2008

```
USE [Students]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [School].[Student_Entry]
        @StudentName = N'Kenny',
        @StudentClass = N'1'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Running above stored procedure enters values in sql server table called Student. But i have like 100 values like this is there an easier way to insert multiple values together? 
or i will have to write above execute statement each time for each value?

Comment: That depends on where those 100 values are now, and whether you must use the stored procedure or are allowed to bypass it and go straight to the table.

Comment: RBarryYoung - Yes i must use stored procedure. Those values are on paper i will have to insert them manually.

Comment: Are you executing the stored procedure in Management Studio(SSMS)?

Comment: You can used table parameters in SQL Server 2008. You'll just have to provide the sp the whole set of rows in a single call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming that you're using SSMS, then you can do this old school: Make the EXEC command into a single line, replace the arguments with "#", cut and paste that line 100 times.  Then replace the "#"'s with the actual arguments from your list and execute.

Here's an example with 10 lines to get you started:

```
USE [Students]
GO

DECLARE @rt int

EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt
EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt
EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt
EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt
EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt
EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt
EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt
EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt
EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt
EXEC @rt = [School].[Student_Entry] @StudentName=N'#', @StudentClass=N'#'; SELECT 'Return Value'=@rt

GO
```

Comment: More drive-by down votes to this technically correct, highly efficient and accepted answer (and the only answer present), yet not one person with the courtesy (or courage) to say why, let alone the intelligence to offer a better answer.  Just one more example of the Rule-By-Ignorance culture here, I suppose.

Comment: Even though I don't know the better approach to achieve this but you solution is not good at all. Imagine who has time to paste something 100 times. What if we want to insert different values change that too. :)

Comment: @Mike 1) Copy the line. 2) Paste it 9 times.  3) Copy all 10 lines. 4) Paste them 9 times.  5) DONE.  This all takes less than 20 seconds, even if you're slow.  OR, ... Writing Code:  Way more than 20 seconds.  The problem with cut-and-paste re-use is NOT how long it takes to do it the first time (which is almost always faster than developing code).  The problem is that 1) it's not common code, and 2) you have to keep re-doing it later.  As this was a one-time need, cut-and-paste re-use is appropriate.